# Optimal way to maintain and quickly look up which objects contain a specific token (string) without maintaining two hash maps?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, data-structures, hashmap

My system takes in a documentID and list of strings that represent tokens associated with the document. The primary metric I am trying to optimize for is returning a list of all the document ids that are associated with a given token. I am pretty confident I should start with something like `HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> tokenLookupMap` where the string is the token and the hash set is the set of documents IDs that contain that token. The tricky part is how to easily deal with documents being overwritten with new token lists (inserts completely overwrite the existing token lists with the new input).  For example if my input looks like:

```
insertDocument(docId: 1, tokens: {token1, token2, token3} )
// query on token1 returns docIDs:[1]
insertDocument(docId: 2, tokens: {token1, token2, token3} )
// query on token1 returns docIDs:[1, 2]
insertDocument(docId: 1, tokens: {token4, token5, token6} )
// query on token1 returns docIDs:[2]
// query on token4 returns docIDs:[1]
```

I need to be able to efficiently update all the values in `tokenLookupMap` to reflect any tokens that are no longer present in the overridden document. Currently I'm maintaining a second hash map `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> documentLookupMap;` to provide the "opposite" lookup perspective such that I can quickly look up what tokens are associated with a given document id and remove the old ones before an overwrite. This definitely allows me to optimize for lookups by token (insert time doesn't matter as much as queries) but it feels silly or even dangerous to have two structs that sort of represent the same thing and share a lot of overlapping space. Aside from the space increase and slight time increase on insert I technically run the risk of the structures getting out of sync.

Are there more optimal ways I could go about this? I could always put the two hash maps in a separate class and lock it down with limited public methods but are there ways to change the structure and perhaps avoid maintaining two structures altogether? Here's the most relevant code:

```
    private HashMap<Integer, HashSet<String>> documentLookupMap;
    private HashMap<String, HashSet<Integer>> tokenLookupMap;

    private void insertDocument(int docId, HashSet<String> tokens ) {

        if( documentLookupMap.containsKey(docId)) {
            // if we've aleady indexed a doc with the same id we need to clean up first
            var oldTokens = documentLookupMap.get(docId);
            for (String token : oldTokens) {
                tokenLookupMap.get(token).remove(docId);
                // not sure if this is beneficial big picture on large data sets / space constraints
                if(tokenLookupMap.get(token).isEmpty()) {
                    tokenLookupMap.remove(token);
                }
            }
        }

        documentLookupMap.put(docId, tokens);
        for (String token : tokens) {
            tokenLookupMap.computeIfAbsent(token,t->new HashSet<Integer>()).add(docId);
        }
    }

    private Set<Integer> getDocsForToken(String token) {
        return tokenLookupMap.containsKey(token) ? tokenLookupMap.get(token) : new HashSet<Integer>();
    }
```

This needs to scale efficiently to tens of thousands of documents / tokens

Thanks in advance for any insights!

Comment: Btw, `tokenLookupMap.containsKey(token) ? tokenLookupMap.get(token)` could be optimized because you're doing the lookup twice. Instead use `Set<Integer> docs = tokenLookupMap.get(token); if( docs == null ) docs = new HashSet();`.

Comment: Thinking some more about your problem it seems like you basically need 2 indices into your data which made me think a DB might be best. Would it be an option to use a specialized DB or even search engine like Lucene? If you need to do it in memory, maybe this can help: https://github.com/npgall/cqengine - it seems to provide a couple of indexing options. If it doesn't provide better performance (I'd assume it requires more memory) then it might at least be a tested and stable implementation to help keep everything in sync.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to my mind would be to maintain the Document-Token relation in separate classes and maintain 2 maps only for lookup:

```
class Document {
  Integer docId;

  //using arrays saves some space and tokens don't seem to change that often
  Token[] tokens;
}

class Token {
  String token;
  Set<Document> documents;
}

Map<Integer, Document> docs = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Token> tokens = new WeakHashMap<>();
```

When inserting a new document you basically clear the set of tokens and rebuild it:

```
private void insertDocument(int docId, Set<String> tokens ) {
  Document doc = docs.computeIfAbsent(docId, ...);
  
  //clear the tokens
  for( Token old : doc.tokens ) {       
    old.documents.remove(doc);
  }
  
  //add the new tokens
  Set<Token> newTokens = new HashSet<>();
  for( String t: tokens ) {
    Token newToken = tokens.computeIfAbsent(t, ...);
    newToken.documents.add(doc);
    newTokens.add(newToken);
  }

  doc.tokens = newTokens.toArray(new Token[0]);
}
```

Of course this could be optimized to ignore tokens that aren't changed.

Note the use of `WeakHashMap` for tokens: since tokens could be abandoned at some point they should not use up any more memory. `WeakHashMap` would allow the garbage collector to remove those that aren't reachably by anyone else, e.g. those that aren't listed in any document.

Of course it could take some time until gc kicks in and in the meantime token lookup could return tokens that aren't used anymore. You'd either need to filter those or remove the tokens from the token map manually if they don't have document references anymore.

Comment: Hey, thanks a ton for posting your thoughts! I’m trying to wrap my head around this and I’m having trouble seeing some of the improvements. Can you elaborate on how this optimizes space / time / readability? The fact that the Document class holds a collection of Token references and vice versa (/and theoretically allows for infinite recursive references) is really throwing me for a loop.

Comment: As for the weakHashMap, I think I may have already addressed relevant concerns by removing entires from ‘ tokenLookupMap’ (please see the example in my question) that point to empty lists. To be clear tokenLookupMap returning stale data is unacceptable. Not sure if that’s possible in your example but I definitely need to avoid that.

Comment: @Blasterdude8 thinking about it some more you're right, this doesn't add too much value. The thinking was that maintaining the bidirectional n:m relationship between documents and tokens could best be encapsulated there with the maps only being indices to find the documents or tokens themselves. But you're right, this probably doesn't have much advantage if any.